# particles for dekiru

Tags: particles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%ab-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning)

I have another question with “dekiru”.

When this verb is used the particle “ni”? For example, like in the following phrase:

> 私にできることなら、よろこんで。

And when is it not?