# How does the に particle work here? (にでき）

Tags: particle-に, potential-form

愛にできること. I am so confused for the usage of the particle に here. This would translate to "things love can do", right? But I've always thought に marks the noun before it, and the action would be done to that noun. So why isn't this translated to "things we can do TO(for) love".
I was thinking more like "母にプレセントを買ってあげた".

Comment: This seems related: [The に particle and potential form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13323/43676)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of に in 「私には本物の若殿様がわかります」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24955/5010) / [Why say “〜、皆には出来る。” instead of “ 〜、皆は出来る。” in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36481/5010) Think of this as "Things that are doable *to* love", if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see an appropriate entry in [a dictionary definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#jn-166083), but this に means にとって for which *for* mostly works as a translation. (愛にとってできること is a bit unnatural, though)

できる is of course *can do*, but here *possible to do* would fit more nicely (in terms of getting a word-by-word translation).

By simply combining these, 愛に-できる-こと = for love - possible to do - things = things it is possible for love to do = things love can do.

Comment: Is there be another particle we can use in place of に ? And how would the meaning vary? 
- 愛ができる: without the こと, this would mean "I can love", right? 
- 愛ができること: I would understand this as "things love can do"
- 愛のできること："love's possible to do things" - does this work?

What if I want to say: Is there anything I can do for you, Ben? (Maybe he's doing some gardening and I want to help).  What would be the most natural thing to say? 
Does "私にできることある？" work?
Also, then how would I say "things I can do for love"?

Comment: All yes to your questions. Just as _for + N_ gives a subject to _to + infinitive_, 愛 in the example is a subject, hence の/が both work. Using の may be less used in speech, so 私に/ができることある are fine. Regarding the last question, it would be 私が愛(のため)にできること. (except _do things for love_  being a little strange. It sounds like 愛 is someone's name.) I think most verbs containing potential meaning work similarly : 彼に/が/の読める本 = a book he can read.