# How does this sentence make sense?

Tags: particle-に, passive-voice, causation

小学生に作れてしまうほど簡単

Each explanation i get is that it means ''Simple enough to be made by schoolchildren''

But how can this be translated to this if this isn't even the passive version of the verb? It seems like the に particle gets weird rules on it's own at times without consistency. I'm pulling my hair out of frustration. I just don't get it.

Comment: This is related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13323/43676

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The に particle and potential form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13323/the-%e3%81%ab-particle-and-potential-form)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now how 小学生に works. 小学生に in this sentence is sort of independent and 作れてしまうほど簡単 is a ''DESCRIBING'' sentence, in other words 小学生に is the main thing while 作れてしまうほど簡単 describes HOW easy it is. so in one way 作れてしまうほど簡単 the verb 作る doesn't convey that it is made ''to'' the students but rather how easy it is BY 小学生に the student to 作れてしまうほど簡単 an action