# Usage of に in sentence 歴史に詳しくない日本人でも卑弥呼という名前を知らない日本人はいない

Tags: particle-に

I am working through [a book about sample texts from Japanese literature](https://www.9640.jp/nihongo/ja/detail/?702) and came around the following sentence:

> 歴史に詳しくない日本人でも卑弥呼という名前を知らない日本人はいない。

**What is this particular use of に？** My current understanding shouts for を instead, although it doesn't sound right as well.

Comment: Possible Duplicates: [Using に with adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13693/using-%e3%81%ab-with-adjectives)

Comment: 詳しい is an adjective.  You need a verb to use を at all.