# Use of に in ぼくにも出来る

Tags: grammar, particle-に

So I was watching the [Pokemon Super Bowl Commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2F46tGehnfo), and around :40 seconds in I hear the phrase

> ぼくにも出来る

Now I know it basically means "I can also do that", but what is the function of the に particle here? Wouldn't ぼくも出来る hold the same meaning still?

Comment: I have always wondered why online Japanese lessons don't tell you to use に with things like できる, and ある and いる (when they mean 'to have'). While you will find them both with and without に, the version with に seems more common in my experience - and I think it's considered more proper.

Comment: @user12399 I always thought of it as meaning 'for'. It is possible even/also for me.

Comment: Related:  [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4440/78).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1)「ボクにもできる。」
>
> 2) "I can also do that."

While those two sentences may be good "translations" for each other, they are structured **very** differently.  It is, indeed, "translation" that often gets in the way of understanding things between the two languages.

The English sentence clearly has a grammatical subject in "I", but the subject is unmentioned in the Japanese sentence.  「ボク」 is not the subject of sentence #1, believe it or not.

> 「ボクにもできる。」 literally means "~~ is doable for me, too."

The ~~ part is just not mentioned because it is understood between the speaker and listener from the larger context/situation.  If one is to actually mention and use it in the sentence, one would say:

> 「ボクにも～～ができる。」

Notice that 「ボク」 is still not the subject of that sentence; 「～～」 is.  It is saying "~~ is doable for me, too.", but only for the sake of naturalness of the translated English sentence, one might use "I can also do ~~", "I can do ~~, too", etc.

Long preface, I know, but from my experience with Japanese-learners, I just know how common this misunderstanding is among them.

Thus, 「に」 is like "to" or "for" as in "X is Y ***to/for*** me" in English.  Once again, this 「に」 does not mark the subject.

This 「に」 is the signature particle used in phrases such as:

> 「Person + に + わかる/できる/[見]{み}える/[言]{い}える, etc.」

Finally, the 「も」 is there for emphasis.  It means "even" here.

In essence, the original sentence literally means:

> "~~ is doable even for me."

Comment: Even though it's not marked by が, it does behave like a subject in multiple ways: (1) 自分 binds to it, e.g., 「太郎に自分の手書きが読める。」「太郎に花小が自分の先生に引きあわせられる。」, (2) it can fill in the missing subject of an adjunct subordinate clause, e.g, 「テレビを見ながら太郎に本が読める。」, (3) 尊敬語 can refer to it, e.g., 「先生にその問題がお分かりになる。」.  ---- And for each of these three things, the argument that *is* marked by が doesn't behave like a subject in that way -- i.e., 自分 cannot bind to it, it can't fill in a missing subject, and 尊敬語 can't refer to it.