# Why wasn't が used instead of には in [そんなこと、私にはとても出来ない。]?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-は, particle-が

Why wasn't が used instead of には in

> [そんなこと、私**には**とても出来ない。]?

Is it correct to use が? What is the meaning/sense and role of には in the sentence to choose it over the が particle?

English:

> There's no way I could do something like that.

Note!!
Same phenomenon in [この本の漢字は難しいので私にはとても読めない。].

Comment: Possible duplicate: (regarding に) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4442/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30841/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/71772/9831, (regarding は) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1121/9831

Answer (score 2):

私には the emphasis is on the "I", suggesting that perhaps some other person may be able, but I am not.　Typicaly this is regarding some skill.

With が the emphasis would be more neutral,  or even focused on the 出来ない．

These forms may also be used in a sense like "I could never do that!"
again emphasis is up to the speaker.