# Adjectives and particles が に

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-は, adjectives, particle-が

Adjectives describe a noun which is marked by が.

> 僕は料理が得意。

Could it be rewritten as

> 僕には料理が得意。

Or is it wrong?

Regarding adjectives, a sentence like this would be correct:

> 僕にはペンが必要です。

Would a sentence like the following one be correct?

> 僕がペンを必要する。

(I think I should say 必要にする, but I am not sure.)

Comment: Rather than 必要する or 必要にする, 必要とする is more appropriate.

Comment: Related: [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4440/542)

Comment: 僕には料理が得意 is ungrammatical.

Comment: I see, thanks.  I was basing it off from the potential and tought it could be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 僕には料理が得意。

is simply ungrammatical.

> 僕にはペンが必要です。

is grammatical only because 必要だ can take two arguments (AがBに) as **word-specific** feature, not that it's a universal grammar for adjectives. It's like the English word [*worth* can have an object but most other adjectives can't](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447990/similar-adjectives-to-worth).

Other adjectives that take に include ふさわしい (あなたが隊長にふさわしい) and 夢中だ (僕は君に夢中だ) etc., but basically you have to learn one by one.

And as already pointed out in comments above:

> × 僕がペンを必要する。
>   僕がペンを必要にする。 → *I make the pens necessary.*
>   僕がペンを必要とする。 → *I necessitate a pen.*

na-adjective + `にする` results in a verb "make ... *adjective*" and `とする` "regard ... *adjective*".

Comment: An edit suggestion included adding a link to the following page, it may be worth taking a look at it and incorporating it if you like it. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447990/similar-adjectives-to-worth

Comment: Done. Thank you @rebuuilt and @ ajsmart.

Answer (score 0):

> 僕には料理が得意

when you say like this, it will give the impression that someone else you are going to talk about is not good at cook.

It's same like this,

> 僕**には**できません
>   I can't do it (but someone can do it)

僕がペンを大切にする can be translated as I care about the pen.