# Function of に in this phrase?

Tags: grammar

> わたしにはわたしとしての考えがあります。
>
> I have my own way of thinking.

I knew に has some basic usage in:

1. Location of Existence
2. Direction and Destination
3. Destination
4. Result of Change
5. Object of Verb
6. Source
7. Specific Time
8. Notion of Per

But I couldn't figure out the use of "に" in this sentence.

Can the literal translation of the above phrase be: "To me, I have my own way of thinking"?

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42803/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> わたし**に**はわたしとしての考えがあります。

The に is closest to #1 on your list: Location of existence.

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> に〘格助詞〙
>   ① (1) ㋐ 存在の場所や**所有する者を表す** 。「机の上に本がある」「母は家にいる」「彼**に**は子供が3人いる」「彼女**に**は責任感が欠けている」

The に indicates the location of existence or the possessor/owner of something.

So your sentence would *literally* translate to: "In me, my own idea exists." ⇒ "I have my own idea."