# How does に fit in here?

Tags: particle-に

> 先生にこんなお孫さんがいたんですか‌

Could someone explain to me how it fits in here and why it works?

I'm still confused about why they use the ''に'' instead of ''は'' here
like this:

> 先生はこんなお孫さんがいたんですか‌

Comment: Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/75062/45489

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks for the link