# What does the term 信じる心に mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-に, song-lyrics

So I was trying to translate the lyrics from the 1st OP of Getter Robo Armageddon anime into my language and right now I'm stuck with this "信じる心に".
It would be very much appreciated if someone could give me an explanation of it.

The full line is:

> 信じる心に明日のために戦うなら

and the English translation I have looked up is

> If you need to fight for your beliefs and for the future

but I don't quite understand.

Full verse for context:

> 勇気はあるか　希望はあるか
> **信じる心に**
> **明日のために　戦うのなら**
> 今がその時だ

Comment: Are you sure it's 信じろ and not 信じる?

Comment: oh right my mistake, it's actually 信じる

Comment: Can you please include what you do/don't understand about it, what's confusing you, etc.?  Otherwise it just sounds like a translation request which is [off-topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: I'm sorry for not saying it clearly, what I questioned about is the particle-に in 信じる心に here, I wonder if you can explain about the use of it in this context. My English is not good so I don't know how to explain my question more particularly with my volcabulary

Answer (score 4):

I think you (or the translator) got the wrong line break. As the form of the lines suggests, it should be

> 勇気はあるか　希望はあるか
> 信じる心に
>
> 明日のために　戦うのなら
> 今がその時だ

The 信じる心**に** is the same one as the following question, meaning 'location' (and by extension 'someone who owns/possesses').

- [The usage of particle「に」：彼女に孫が一人いる。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/75062/45489)

The first line is inverted and the normal order is 信じる心に勇気はあるか、希望はあるか, which means *Is there courage, is there hope in the believing heart?*.

The latter part is straightforward: *If you fight for tomorrow, now is the time*.