# what does に in the paragraph below mean

Tags: grammar

> 人が個性について語る場合、どうもいい個性のことばかりを取り上げているように思う。いい個性は伸ばし、悪い個性は直しましょう、というわけだ。しかし、私にとってはどちらも大切にすべき個性であるし、そもそもこうしたもの**に**いいも悪いもないのである。

I don't know what the sentence "そもそもこうしたものにいいも悪いもないのである" exactly means. I can only guess its meaning from context, that "this kind of matter is not something that can be described as good or bad".

Answer (score 2):

This に is an (abstract) location marker used with ない (and existence verbs such as ある and いる). Here, いい and 悪い are used as nouns.

- [Cases where "に" cannot mean "at"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42803/5010)
- [The usage of particle「に」：彼女に孫が一人いる。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/75062/5010)

> こうしたもの**に**いいも悪いもないのである。
> There is no *good* or *bad* **in** such things.

こうしたもの refers to 個性, so the author is saying that there is no such thing as "good personality" or "bad personality" to begin with.