# What purpose does the particle に serve in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 人に出来ること**に**は限りがある

What is the point of the second に? Would the sentence have a different meaning or be grammatically incorrect if it was just 人に出来ることは限りがある?
Any help in understanding this would be very helpful because I feel like I often see this construction.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42803/5010

Answer (score 1):

「に」is needed here because of 「ある」. This is a 「B に A がある/いる」 "There is A in/at B" construction.

「は」is a topic marker that elevates the location/place (B) to the topic. The subject is the thing (A) that exists.