# what does に do in this sentence これがある限り俺たちに拒否権はない

Tags: particles, particle-に, video-games

I saw this sentence in the final fantasy 16 trailer

> これがある限り俺たち**に**拒否権はない

I'm aware it means

> as long as we have this we have no right to refuse

but I'm confused by why **に** is used here I was under the impression that **に** worked with verbs indicating the target of an action with the exception of adverbs and some old usage of **に** meaning と sometimes

I didn't know of other uses for  but I'm seeing more and more than maybe **に** can be extended to mean some other things is this an extend use of **に** if so how should I think of it or am I missing something

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%ab-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning/4442#4442

Comment: What particle do you think is more natural in its place?

Answer (score 2):

I like this [explanation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42816/43676). This usage of に is not much different from that in 鳥取県にスタバはない. A right to refuse doesn’t exist in us.