# What's the use of に in「古見さんに友達が増えた」?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearningJapanese/comments/qgxcev/the_use_of_ni_in_this_sentence_i_thought_ni_was/) question on Reddit piqued my interest, and as of now doesn't have an adequate answer. The sentence in question is:

> 古見さん**に**友達が増えた. Komi-san made a new friend.

I know に is a very versatile case particle with many meanings, but what is the specific usage here?  Any other example sentences with this type of に?  How is the nuance different from 「古見さん**の**友達が増えた」 or 「古見さん**は**友達が増えた」?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not much different from sentences like this.

> 駅前に店ができた。

This できる describes a change of state, a kind that puts something into existence somewhere. That *somewhere* is marked with に. This usage of に could be seen as basically the same as the standard usage of the particle in the sentence below, except the *existence* described will happen only as a result of the change described by the verb.

> 駅前に店がある。

増える in your sentence works in a similar manner. As a result of the described change, Komi-san has a new friend or friends, or they *come into existence in* Komi-san. In fact, this state can be described as below.

> 古味さんに（新しい）友達がいる。

(This usage of に is discussed [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42803/43676).)

増える doesn’t always work like that, though. For example, 人口が増える doesn’t describe a change that newly puts something into existence somewhere. It merely describes a change in some variable. So, the following sentence is a bit strange.

> 日本に人口が増えた。

Comment: What's the correct phrasing for 日本に人口が増えた。Is it は, の, or で? My guess would be の, and は is almost always suitable.

Answer (score 5):

I think the English translation is misleading here. Literal translation will be  "Komi-san's friend(s) became more numerous", or even more literal "Friends became more numerous at/for/to Komi-san". So friend(s) are the actor and  Komi-san is a recepient. As such she is marked with "ni". But of course she can be marked with "ha" as well.

It works similarly in Russian, so it's not peculiar to Japanese.