# Difference between に and が

Tags: particle-に, particle-が

What's the difference between their に and が in these sentences?

> 「私にできることがあれば何でも言ってください」

and

> 「私ができることがあれば何でも言ってください」?

Comment: Welcome to JLSE!  You may not be aware, but there are certain questions that are considered off-topic.  Our goal is to help individuals learn the language, not provide a bulk translation site.  If you give us your translation attempts, we will be better able to give you an answer that meets your needs as a student of the language.  See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think these essentially mean the same thing, however "に" feels much more common, and が may be incorrect in this context. I think the reason is because が before できる would usually indicate what can be done, not who can do it (ex: 仕事が出来る）

Comment: 「私ができることがあれば何でも言ってください」 sounds a little bit strange. Ask me anything if you have something that only I can do (other people can not do the task). On the other hand,「私にできることがあれば何でも言ってください」 Ask me anything if you have something that I can do (probably other people can do the task, too).

Comment: Either will do. They are not particularly different. If any, the one with に feels somehow more orthodox because it has been used since earlier time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4440/542)

Answer (score 0):

> (1) 私**に**できることがあれば何でも言ってください。
>   (2) 私**が**できることがあれば何でも言ってください。

- Sentence (1) and (2) have nearly the same meaning, and they make sense.
- (1) is commonly used but (2) is rarely used in the situation where offering  one's help to others.
- Compared to (1), there is a nuance in (2) that the speaker is arrogant. Conversely, (1) is very modest about the attitude of the offering help compared to (2).
- The nuance of modesty that the sentence of (1) has depends on "に" in it. According to jisho.org, the definition of "に" in this sentence corresponds to "in the role of" of 6 written below.

> 6の意味で「私**に**できることがあれば」を丁寧に解釈すると、
>   「色々な人があなたへ色々な種類の援助できると思いますが、その中で、私**にふさわしい役割として**できることがあれば」と言う意味になります。
>   *If I carefully interpret the phrase "私**に**できることがあれば" in the sense of "in the role of" for "に", the phrase would be like*:
>   "*I think that various people can offer various kinds of assistance to you, but if there is something that could be done **as a suitable role for me***".

The difinition of に in jisho.org [here](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB):

> #### に
>
> Particle
>   1. at (place, time); in; on; during​
>   2. to (direction, state); toward; into
>   3. for (purpose)​
>   4. because of (reason); for; with
>   5. by; from​
>   6. **as (i.e. in the role of) ​See also として**
>   7. per; in; for; a (e.g. "once a month")​
>   8. and; in addition to​
>   9. if; although​
>   10. Ni(kana) に、二