# I don't understand why my は was changed to a に when a native corrected my sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-は, particle-も

> My sentence: 彼はこれを出来るなら僕は矢っ張り出来る
>
> Correction: 彼にそれが出来るなら、僕にもできる

I can understand the rest of the changes, but why はー＞に ? All they said was that it sounded more natural but they weren't sure why. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: This might be worth a look: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%ab-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tl;dr: 「は」 is a big no-no for the subject marker in if-clauses.

A two-step explanation will be in order here.

First, there is a big grammar rule that says "**DO NOT use 「は」 as the subject marker in an if-clause.  Use 「が」 for that**."

Correct:「キミ**が**行{い}くなら、ボク**も**行く。」

Incorrect:「キミ**は**行くなら、ボク**も**行く。」

This seems to be a very common mistake among Japanese-learners.  SE is no exception at all.

Secondly, 「できる」, which is used in your sentence, is a special verb that can take 「に」 with the subject as in 「(person) + に + できる」.  However, the が-over-は rule for the if-clauses still stands, which is why it is **incorrect** to say:

> 「彼**は**できるなら、ボク**は**やっぱりできる。」

which is essentially what you wrote.

That is because the first part of that sentence is an if-clause as it uses 「なら」.　You just cannot use 「は」 there.  Thus, it is only ***correct*** to say:

> 「彼**が**できるなら、ボク（に）もできる。」

But as I mentioned above, it is more natural to use 「に」 than 「は/が」 with 「できる」.  Thus, your teacher/friend corrected your sentence that used 「は」 to:

「彼**に**それ**が**出来るなら、僕**にも**できる。」