# 誰も + potential verb form

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-も, potential-form

I'm pretty sure "誰にも読めない本" is correct. However, I have also heard something in the same vein as "誰も読めない本", without the に. Is this also correct?
If so, does も replace が here?

Comment: Is this not actually a question about particle use with potential verbs (not about 誰も)?

Comment: Related: [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4440/78)

Answer (score 1):

> 誰も読めない本, without the に. Is this also correct?

Yes, it is correct in this case.

> If so, does も replace が here?

No, it cannot be replaced. 誰も読めない本 is correct. 誰が読めない本 is incorrect. Japanese people never say it like this.