# Can someone explain to me the function of に in this phrase?

Tags: particle-に

[image: luffy vs katakuri]

So, I was reading my favorite manga, until I got stuck all of a sudden in this particular phrase highlighted in red. I had to go check the english translation, and it translated as "there's nothing your powers can do that mine can't".

I believe this is right and it makes sense, but even so I just can't understand the logic of the phrase in japanese, because of the に. This particle is by far the one that gives me most nightmares and its the last one for me to conquer.

What would be the function of に in this phrase? Wouldn't be also right if it was が instead of に? Do both に express the same meaning or they express different meanings?

Fortunately I understand the majority of the に appearances, but sometimes I just get hit by some awful phrases that I have to solve like its some sort of rubik's cube. I would love some help with this one, because I just can't connect it in my brain and with the translated version. Thanks!

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4440/43676

Comment: Which に are you referring to?