Understanding [Noun + には思えた]

おばさんの目が意味ありげに光ったように、信也には思えた。

I understand that 思えた here means "to appear likely" and a phrase such as 奇妙に思えた means "to appear strange". But given that we have a character name before the に particle, how should 信也には思えた be parsed? Could it be that the 思えた is actually the potential form of 思う?

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%ab-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning

AにはBに思える means "(It) strikes A as B":

私には奇妙に思えます。
It strikes me as peculiar.

(If B is an i-adjective, the ku-form is used: 私にはおかしく思えます)
Your sentence is structurally almost the same as this, except that the impression part (B) is longer, and thus the order of A and B is reversed:

おばさんの目が意味ありげに光ったように、信也には思えた。
= 信也には、おばさんの目が意味ありげに光ったように思えた。
It struck Shinya that the woman's eyes gleamed meaningfully.

